# Installing Kubuntu or Gnome3 on ubuntu

Tags: kubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I like default unity desktop environment, but now I want to try Kubuntu.
So please tell me a way to do that.

I should have options for choosing which desktop environment to start at log in screen as i do not want to replace unity with KDE.
So please help me...
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times. `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`. no ppa are required.

Comment: Why do you so eagerly to use a PPA? You can install both KDE and Gnome Shell without a PPA.

Comment: when i try  sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop it shows   Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kubuntu-desktop : Depends: software-properties-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: apturl-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: libreoffice-base but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: libreoffice-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: muon-discover but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: muon-notifier but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Recommends: usb-creator-kde but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @Krishna - see the link I gave you already. you are having this problem as you are using ppa rather then the standard repos and testing ppa at that. This is why the answer you were following received down votes. I am sorry you followed bad advice.

Answer (score -1):

for Kubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

EDIT: for gnome3

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Comment: I got problem on second step. It shows W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/next-backports/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: list down the errors you have

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/next-backports/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: It seesms link is dropped so remove it and use this instead `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:neon/kf5`

Comment: ok. I am trying...

Comment: Now it shows   Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:neon/kf5'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.

Comment: Please give me GNOME 3 PPA repository link instead

Comment: ok wait a second

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging

Comment: what should be last step... sudo apt-get install kubuntu-plasma5-desktop plasma-workspace-wallpapers  replace with

Comment: NO `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`

Comment: You can install kde without using a ppa  at all - `sudo apt-get install kubuntu desktoop`

Comment: @bodhi.zazen thanks but i think you have typo `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer because of recomending a PPA without motive or reason and also because making not mention that installing and upgrading Gnome from this source would monstly posible break Unity desktop.

Comment: after applying sudo apt-get dist-upgrade , it broke unity and i was unable to log in to ubuntu.  after that somehow i manage to install unity again...

Comment: then when i try sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop  it shows

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Comment: Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Recommends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-gnome-desktop : Depends: gdm but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-session but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-settings-daemon but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-shell-extensions but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.